# compiling a simple gtk program with glade

Tags: c, gtk, glade

i hav downloaded glade3 and i cant find any glade.h in it when i extract it so when i compile the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glade/glade.h>



GladeXML *xml;
GtkWidget *widget;
GtkWidget *display;



G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_displayButton_clicked(GtkButton *button,gpointer *data)
{
/* Find the Glade XML tree containing widget. */
xml = glade_get_widget_tree(GTK_WIDGET( widget ));

/* Pull the widgets out of the tree */
display= glade_xml_get_widget(xml, "displayLabel");

gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(display),"Hello World!\n gihansblog.com");
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_exitButton_clicked(GtkButton *button,gpointer *data)
{
gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

/*import glade file*/
xml = glade_xml_new("hello.glade", NULL, NULL);

/* get a widget (useful if you want to change something) */
widget = glade_xml_get_widget(xml, "mainWindow");

/* connect signal handlers */
glade_xml_signal_autoconnect(xml);

/*show widget*/
gtk_widget_show (widget);

gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```

i get an error saying glade.h not found,i have been working on it from past 5 hours but cant find a solution.

Comment: Seems that you need to install libglade

Comment: i have installed libglade and now i get an error saying undefined reference to glade_get_widget_tree

Comment: @user3831551 did you ever manage to fix the issue? I'm having the same problem "undefined reference to glade_get_widget_tree".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by giving the full directory to your

> "hello.glade" file.

Where it is in your system???

Otherwise you may have to convert your .glade file to .xml

Anyway in which Gtk version aru you in?